# Вывод количества постов категории в Sidebar через код Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

Должно получиться вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Практически все сделал, но застрял на выводе кол-ва записей справа от рубрик. Выводится кол-во постов той рубрики на которой ты сейчас находишься. Тоесть если в первой рубрике 3 поста все цифры будут 3, если у второй рубрики 10 записей - все цифры будут изменены на 10

```
<?php

                $test_categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
                $categories_link_array = array();
                
                //$categoryss = get_queried_object() ->count;
                //$category_total = $category->count;                                       //Подсчет постов в рубриках

                foreach( $test_categories as $cat ) {
                    $categoryss = get_queried_object($cat) ->count;

                    $categories_link_array[] = '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link($cat->term_id) . '">' .$cat->name .  '<span>' . $categoryss . '</span></a></li>';
                }
                echo implode('', $categories_link_array);

             ?>
```

Я так понимаю должен обозначить в цикле foreach что считать нужно именно ту категорию которая $cat, но где это вписать точно - не в курсе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_categories#show_count

Comment: Получилось, а как теперь обернуть кол-во (цифры) в <span></span>. И еще, как сделать так, чтобы все рубрики выводились в <li> и можно было присвоить определенный класс? Тоесть как использовать html с данной функцией?

Answer (score 0):

Вот правильный ответ:

```
            <ul>
                <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'orderby' => 'slug',
                        'hide_empty'   => 1,
                    );
                    $categories = get_categories( $args );
                    foreach( $categories as $category ){
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '<span>' . $category->category_count . '</span></a></li>';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
```